# Expression Tree parsing, variables ends up as constants

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, tree, expression

So I'm working on a project where I need to parse an expression tree. I got most of the things working, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

I've been looking at the other questions on StackOverflow on Expression Trees, but can't seem to find an answer to my question, so here goes.

My problem is the difference (or lack of) between constants and variables. Let me start off with an example:

```
user => user.Email == email
```

This is clearly not a constant but a variable, but this ends up being a ConstantExpression somewhere in the expression tree. If you take a look at the expression itself, it looks a bit odd:

```
Expression = {value(stORM.Web.Security.User+<>c__DisplayClassa)}
```

If we take another example:

```
task => task.Status != TaskStatus.Done && t.Status != TaskStatus.Failed
```

Here I'm using an ENUM (TaskStatus).

So my problem is that in the tree parsing I seem to end up with a ConstantExpression in both cases, and I really need to be able to tell them apart. These are just examples, so what I'm asking is a generic way of telling these two types of expression from each other, so I can handle then in 2 different ways in my parsing.

EDIT: okay, my examples might not be clear, so I'll try again. First example:

User user = db.Search < User > (u => u.Email == email);

I'm trying to find a user with the given e-mail address. I'm parsing this into a stored procedure, but that's besides the point I guess.

Second example:

IList < Task > tasks = db.Search(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.Done && t.Status != TaskStatus.Failed);

And here I'm trying to locate all tasks with a status different from Done and Failed.
Again this is being parsing into a stored procedure. In the first example my code needs to determine that the stored procedure needs a input parameter, the value of the email variable. In the second example I don't need any input parameters, I just need to create the SQL for selecting task with a status different from Done and Failed.

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

So from the point of view of expression the value is a constant. It can not be changed by the expression.

What you have is a potentially open closure - i.e. the value can change between executions of the expression, but not during it. So it is a "constant". This is a paradigm difference between the world of functional programming and un-functional :) programming.

Consider

```
        int a =2;
        Expression<Func<int, int>> h = x=> x+ a;
        Expression<Func<int, int>> j = x => x +2;
        a = 1;
```

the term a is a member access into an anonymous class that wraps up and access the a variable on the stack. The first node is a MemberAccess node then underneath that - the expression is a constant.

For the code above:

```
((SimpleBinaryExpression)(h.Body)).Right
{value(WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0).a}
    CanReduce: false
    DebugView: ".Constant<WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0>(WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0).a"
    Expression: {value(WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0)}
    Member: {Int32 a}
    NodeType: MemberAccess
    Type: {Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"}
```

And the constant underneath that:

```
((MemberExpression)((SimpleBinaryExpression)(h.Body)).Right).Expression
{value(WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0)}
    CanReduce: false
    DebugView: ".Constant<WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0>(WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0)"
    NodeType: Constant
    Type: {Name = "<>c__DisplayClass0" FullName = "WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass0"}
    Value: {WindowsFormsApplication6.Form1.}
        }
    }
```

The plain old 2 comes out to a:

```
((SimpleBinaryExpression)(j.Body)).Right
{2}
    CanReduce: false
    DebugView: "2"
    NodeType: Constant
    Type: {Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"}
    Value: 2
```

So I don't know if that helps you or not. You can kind of tell by looking at the parent node - or the type of object being accessed by the parent node.

---

Adding as a result of your clarification -

so when you say

```
user => user.Email == email
```

You mean look for all users with an email equal to a passed in parameter - however that link expression means something quite different.

what you want to say is

```
Expression<Func<User, string, bool>> (user, email) => user.Email == email
```

This way the email will now be a parameter. If you don't like that there is one other thing you can do.

The second example will work just fine - no extra params are needed consts will be consts.

```
t => t.Status != TaskStatus.Done && t.Status != TaskStatus.Failed
```

---

Edit: adding another way:

So one of the things that you had to do to get your code working was declare a string email outside the lambda - that is kind of clunky.

You could better identify parameters by conventionally putting them in a specific place - like a static class. Then when going through the Lambda you don't have to look at some horrible cloture object - but a nice static class of your making.

```
public static class Parameter
{
    public static T Input<T>(string name)
    {
        return default(T);
    }  
}
```

Then your code looks like this:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp = x => x.Email == Parameter.Input<String>("email");
```

You can then traverse the tree - when you come to a call to to the Parameter static class you can look at the type and the name (in the arguments collection) and off you go....

Comment: I'll take a look at the parent node as you suggest and see what that gets me! Thanks. I'll post up my findings here!

Comment: Wait a second - what might be going on is this ... do you have a local user defined, and it is trying to pull that instance in as a cloture. What you might want to do is Expression<Func<User, bool>> x=>x.email == email; I think you might have gotten confused between a local instance and a desired input?

Comment: Added some more to the question to clarify the problem. I'll still take a look at the parent node and see where that gets me.

Comment: That does look a bit verbose. Actually for now I've got it fixed by looking at the "parent" expression, but I would be interested in knowing what other suggestion you have for fixing it. This is my first project working with expression so I'm still learning!

Answer (score 2):

The name is a bit unfortunate, it is not actually a constant.

It simply refers to a value outside the Expression.

Answer (score 2):

A captured variable (the first case with `email`) is typically a `ConstantExpression` representing the *capture class instance*, with a `MemberExpression` to a `FieldInfo` for the "variable" - as if you had:

```
private class CaptureClass {
    public string email;
}
...
var obj = new CaptureClass();
obj.email = "foo@bar.com";
```

Here, `obj` is the constant inside the expression.

So: if you see a `MemberExpression` (of a field) to a `ConstantExpression`, it is *probably* a captured variable. You could also check for `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` on the capture-class...

A *literal* constant will typically *just* be a `ConstantExpression`; in fact, it would be hard to think of a scenario where you use a constant's member, unless you could something like:

```
() => "abc".Length
```

but here `.Length` is a *property* (not a field), and the string probably doesn't have `[CompilerGenerated]`.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in my question, but Email is actually a property on the user object.

Comment: @SteenT - and what does the expression tree look like? It *might* be the same thing, silently capturing `this` (since `email` is implicitly `this.email`). So I *might* expect `Member("email", Member("this", captureClass))` (if you see what I mean)

Comment: @SteenT - ah, in my answer I was talking about `email` on the right hand side. The comment above should explain the `user.Email` on the left...

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Type of the ConstantExpression. Any 'constant' ConstantExpression has a primitive type.